# Redis C# - Using Incr value in a transaction

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying use Redis INCR and the incremented value to be used as a field in a Hash from C# using StackExchange.Redis.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757935/redis-using-incr-value-in-a-transaction) points similar to what I need, but in Node.

The below is something like I need.

```cs
            ITransaction transation = m_connection.GetDatabase()
                                                  .CreateTransaction();
            Task<long> incrementTask = transation.StringIncrementAsync(sequenceNumberRedisKey);


            if (await transation.ExecuteAsync())
            {
                long sequenceNumber = await incrementTask;
                await transation.HashSetAsync(responseRedisKey, sequenceNumber, response);
            }
```

Note that `sequenceNumber` is the result of the first operation I intend to do in the transaction.

The code seems like the transaction executes and commits before I even do any of my operations.

1. Is this the way to do multiple operations in one transaction?
2. Is this the way I could use the result of operation 1 (StringIncrementAsync) in operation 2 (HashSetAsync) ?
3. How do I rollback the sequence number increment if HashSetAsync returns false?
4. Why is there no explicit commit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fundamental feature of redis MULTI/EXEC units that means you *cannot* get results during the operation. As such, there are two common ways of doing what you ask:

1. Use Lua (`ScriptEvaluate[Async]`); a Lua script executes on the server start-to-end, is efficient, and avoids all problems associated with round-trip time (latency or bandwidth) or competition from other connections
2. Use an optimistic loop that reads the current value, then creates a transaction in SE-Redis that adds a **constraint** that the value you just read is the same, and execute the side-effects inside the transaction; the library will co-ordinate the necessary WATCH etc machinery to make this robust, but if the constraint condition turns out to be invalid (i.e. the library returns `false`), you need to redo everything from the start

Frankly, these days I would always guide people to option 1; option 2 is only "appealing" (and I use that term quite incorrectly) if server-side Lua scripting is not available.

I'm not at a PC, but I'm guessing the script would look something like:

```lua
local id = redis.call("incr", KEYS[1])
redis.call("hset", KEYS[2], tostring(id), ARGV[1])
return id
```

Comment: What is the best practice around here? Is there a library that I can use in a .NET Core application to write C# to Lua? where do I keep the script. Can i have it written to Redis like a Stored Procedure/

Comment: @JinsPeter the method shown above should do that; the library handles all the `SCRIPT LOAD` etc semantics, so that it doesn't send the entire body each time. If you are handling the load yourself (not recommended, due to unload problems): the library detects if you are issuing a SHA hash, and reacts accordingly. Here's the redis docs: https://redis.io/commands/eval - you just pass the script and keys/values to ScriptEvaluate

Comment: @MarkGravell  I am using StackExchange.Redis as my redis library. And the abvove lua script is doing exactly what I need. But for an application perspective.
So are you recommending `EVAL` `(LuaScript.ScriptEvaluate)` over `EVALSHA` `(LoadedLuaScript.ScriptEvaluate)`  ? It is not very clear from the comment

Comment: @JinsPeter ScriptEvaluate already uses EVALSHA most of the time - you don't need LoadedLuaScript for that; that is a niche advanced API, and to be honest: I like keeping things simple, so I usually just advise to use ScriptEvaluate

Comment: Does this make [this documentation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/docs/Scripting.md) a bit misleading. Shall I Raise a PR to make clarity in that doc?

Comment: @JinsPeter yes, that does look a little incomplete, to the point where it could mislead; what *actually* happens is: if the script string *is* a SHA, it uses EVALSHA directly; otherwise, the library keeps track of what scripts it knows about - if it doesn't think a script has been loaded, the library (when it can, which isn't always) issues SCRIPT LOAD automatically; once that has been confirmed, it uses EVALSHA - until then: EVAL. It also detects the error from EVALSHA that indicates it was unloaded, and re-issues the SCRIPT LOAD etc.

Comment: @JinsPeter or put more simply: the library makes it "just work" :)

Comment: I was running with this Redis monitor and found behaviour like this you said above. Really liked it. I was wondering how this was implemented. Thanks for explaining that. So, Could we safely say that script would most often be a SHA in the life of a one connection? I mean, until the redis connection/connections are disposed?

Comment: @JinsPeter yes - unless it detects an error from the server indicating that the script isn't loaded, presumably because somebody on another connection issued `SCRIPT FLUSH`